# VisualComposer - custom layout for block

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, visual-composer

In wordpress visual composer I have block with some articles and I want to display them in custom way so I need to add some layout which can be available from layouts list (screen below). What is the correct way to add custom layout for some elements? I don't want to lose my custom layout during vc update.[image]